# On applying Selenium Grid concept only one random node among several nodes is chosen for execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-grid

On applying Selenium Grid concept only one random node among several nodes is chosen for execution. How to make the same test to be executed on multiple nodes?
The combination I use to execute the script: Selenium(Java)+Junit Framework.

Comment: because than only one node fits the required capabilities

Comment: I've been using the same config(browsers) for all nodes. @HenningLuther

Comment: are u running your tests parallel?

Comment: No, i'm not running tests parallel. @HenningLuther

Comment: than only one node is accessed, you need to run them parallel to see multiple browsers used at the same time, grid makes only sense in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say, the same script should be executed on desired node on each time of execution. So that you can test on particular node. if your nodes are different configuration than you can try using the other parameter/capabilities like OS name, browser version, etc...

Comment: Any node can be accessed but i need to run the script among all the nodes! consider like 3 users hitting the application from 3 different machine(with same version of browsers and OS), to achieve this i had used 'Selenium Grid' concept, but on executing the script in grid executes the script only on one of the nodes. @Murthi

Comment: This can be achieved with testng with parallel attribute using suite XML file. But I don't have idea using junit. If you are using maven then you trigger the same script with three different command prompt in same machines. It will trigger same script on each node.